# Transforming a 2D array to a list

Tags: python, arrays, list

Let's assume I have an 2D array named 'example'

```
example = np.array([[14],[34],[234],[17],[80],[4563],[1456],[2345],[3456],[34565]])
```

What I want to do here is to transform the array to a list that looks like:

[14, 34, 234, 17, 80, 4563, 1456, 2345, 3456, 34565]

How can I get the above list from the array?

Comment: That's an array, not an array of lists

Comment: You can use hstack:  np.hstack(example).tolist()

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way, as it seems to be the most natural expression of what you're trying to do:

```
example.flatten().tolist()
```

Comment: Probably, the OP should stick to an array. Who knows. But they are certainly confused about what is in their array. If it *were* an array of lists, this wouldn't actually work.